# allauth tests return errors

Tags: django, authentication

For changing things like translations in forms i included allauth app directly in my project but now when i want to run tests it returns lots of errors i think it runs every test while i am not using social logins it tests it and fails

my project on Github : github.com/MrHamedi/VSC/tree/dev

Shall i delete allauth test to resolve this problem ? or what should i do so allauth tests only test allauth.account tests

Comment: You installed an entire app just to use its translations?
Instead you could borrow their .po file contents.

Comment: No i meant instead of installing it in virtual environment i installed it directly but now it runs whole apps tests while i dont use the whole app which makes errors !! i think maybe including it directly is wrong to do but the other way i cant translate forms by myself

Comment: Ahh now i see, so instead of installing it via pip you copied the package to your project. In that case, yes you could delete the tests.
If you are not planning on using it you should copy their locale folders contents to your locale folder, so you can use their translations without having to keep the package at all